# Какие есть аналоги элемента WebBrowser для С# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Со стандартным элементом возникла проблема, что он не адекватно обрабатывает JS-код.

Comment: а почему вопрос прикрыли так и не понял?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- WebKit.NET
- CefSharp
- A Real WPF WebBrowser

Источник: [WebKit.NET или CefSharp ?](https://toster.ru/q/6416)

- xulrunner
- Awesomium

Источник: [Как подключить сторонний браузер в приложении на C#](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170015/)

Comment: Не подскажешь почему прикрыли этот вопрос?